# When is a sequence allowed to be integrated partwise (Lebesgue)?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

This is an exercise from Heuser Analysis 2 :

Let 
$$f_n \in L(I); \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n =_{a.e} f $$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ let also : $$|f_n-f|\le h$$ where h is a nonnegative Lebesgue integrable function

Heuser asks to show  that: $$f\in L(I) \ \text{and the sequence $f_n$ may be integrated partwise }$$

and that the same applies, too , if the function $h$ is replaced by a certain constant $M $

What I have tried so far:

I tried to apply the theorem of beppo-levi , i.e. that: every monotonuous sequence of functions $f_n \in L(I)$ with a bounded integral sequence $(\int_{a}^{b} f_n dx)$ converges almost everywhere  to a function of $L(I)$ and may be integrated partwise that means: $$\int_{a}^{b}f_n dx \rightarrow \int_{a}^{b} f dx$$ but to no avail.

Do you see how to show this? Please do point me to the right direction then!

Comment: Is $I$ a bounded interval? What is $L(I)$? Is $L(I)=L^1(I)$?

Comment: $I:=[a,b]$ , $L(I) $ denotes all lebesgue integrable functions on that interval

Comment: You can use Lebesgue Theorem on the sequence $g_n=f_n-f$.

Comment: Do you mean the theorem of dominant convergence? I don't understand what you mean with using it on the sequence $g_n = f_n-f$